# Merge "spam" tags

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Questions tagged [spam](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spam) are pretty much, by definition, about how to prevent spam. (I can't think of any questions that we would want here that wouldn't be.)

I suggest, then, that the following tags be made synonyms of and merged to [spam](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spam):

- [spam-prevention](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spam-prevention)
- [anti-spam](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anti-spam) (and its synonym [antispam](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antispam))

I suppose an argument could be made that [spam-prevention](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spam-prevention) should be the "master" tag, but that and [anti-spam](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anti-spam) are obviously the same thing.

Comment: That this is possibly a meta-tag is another discussion.

Comment: Some people, marketers I think, use the term "spam" as it was a good thing. Anyway, I agree with you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions! This is done.

[image]